# Output an object using "For Each" to an excel Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this section of code using regular functions:

```
Set Matches = oReg.Execute(tack)
For Each oMatch In Matches
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, t) = oMatch.Value
    t = t + 1       
Next
```

And I am having trouble printing the `oMatch.Value` in different cells in my worksheet, they are all printed in the same cell

How could I change it to write the values to different cells?

Comment: How are you defining `i` and `t` and settings initial values? From the code you provided it should move each value into the next column though it doesn't show where you defined `t` and set its initial value. In a non explicit context I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Might be that there is only 1 row returned from your query. Can you advise how you are defining `Matches`? I imagine its a recordset. If it is could you place a break after your query and check on the Watch screen what values its being passed?

Comment: @nbayly, it's not a query, it's a list of matches from a regex expression. Is `Matches` a variant? Can you post your full code?

Comment: Hmm... If `Matches` is an 1D array he could directly output it like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Ubound(Matches) [+ 1]).Value = Matches` (the +1 only if base is `0`)... this way no loop is needed... (but it will not work if `Matches` is a collection or some kind of object)

Answer (score 0):

This code put each of two matches in separate cells

```
Sub test()

    Dim RE As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, REMatches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim REMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    Dim strData As String
    Dim i As Long, t As Long

    strData = "[step 1] title for substeps;  [substep a] step a; [substep b] step b; [substep c] step c;"
    i = 1: t = 1

    Set RE = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\[substep [a-zA-Z]\](.*?); {1}"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)

    For Each REMatch In REMatches
        Sheet1.Cells(i, t) = REMatch.Value
        t = t + 1
    Next REMatch

End Sub
```

Right before your loop, put `Debug.Print Matches.Count` to make sure there's more than one match. Also, if you don't set Global to True, you'll only get one match.